# Adding chili powder to a dish makes it dark black

Tags: food-safety, chili-peppers, color

Chili powder was homemade, Chilies were dried and sent to nearby mill to grind and make it fine. When I started using this powder it makes the dish black and it looks black but tastes fine. Wondering what contaminated the powder, does anyone have any similar experiences?

Comment: Most likely nothing contaminated the powder, dark chilis make dark powder.

Comment: For a comparison see [Aleppo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleppo_pepper) vs [Urfa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urfa_biber) peppers.

Comment: Not an answer, but in the future, consider just keeping your dried chiles whole, then rehydrating with cooking liquid and blending at use time. The volatile oils will last longer in the whole chiles, as with other whole spices vs. their ground equivalents.

Comment: Were the chillies dark as a whole? Or were they more the red variant?

Comment: The chillier were red variant not dark

Answer (score 12):

I make my own chili powder by drying (already dried) chilies in the oven till crispy. I then add them to a food processor and grind them to a rough powder.

The result is a **very** dark chili powder that will often darken what it is added to substantially. If I cover a steak with it the steak is blackened. Adding it to lighter soups and stews also darkens them substantially.

As you send your chili powder out to be professionally ground it likely comes out much more finely ground than my inexpensive, old, food processor. And because of that is likely to color anything you add it to more than mine.

Like @GdD said I would bet this is what is happening with your chili powder.